# Solving Boolean equations

Tags: equation-solving, code-request

[image]

@Artes suggested this code to me to solve this system of equations:

```
'x[a_, b_] := Boole[a >= b] 
y[a_, c_] := Boole[a >= c]
z[b_, c_] := Boole[b >= c]
Solve[ a == x[a, b] + y[a, c] && b == x[a, b] + z[b, c] && 
       c == y[a, c] + z[b, c], {a, b, c}]'
```

What's the fastest way to get to the solution of x[a_, b_], which should be a parameter now.

A problem which arised while coding the above was, that this code

```
 H[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; 10 - x - y >= p[B2] - y && 10 - x - y >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 1 /; 6 - x > p[B2] - y && 6 - x >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 0.5 /; 4 - x == p[B2] - y && 4 - x >= 0
H[1, x_, y_] := 0 /; others
```

doesn't work for me.

```
P[q_, w_] := 1 /; q > w  
P[q_, w_] := 0 /; others  
P[q_, w_] := 0.5 /; q == w
```

This code on the other hand works fine. So i suppose that "others" in the case of multiple conditions doesn't work any longer. Is there a solution?

Comment: try `Boole` and `Reduce` or `FindInstance`

Comment: Don't delete previous information of your question since it makes the answers to it unreasonable. Have you looked at the documentation pages? If so, why can't you resolve your problem? If you demonstrate your attempts it will be likely someone'll provide the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's define the following functions:

```
x[a_, b_] := Boole[a >= b] 
y[a_, c_] := Boole[a >= c]
z[b_, c_] := Boole[b >= c]
```

In fact we need only one function but for clarity of dealing with variables we have used three definitions, 
then we rewrite the given system

```
Solve[ a == x[a, b] + y[a, c] && b == x[a, b] + z[b, c] && 
       c == y[a, c] + z[b, c], {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 0, b -> 1, c -> 1}, {a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 2}}
> ```

alternatively

```
Reduce[ a == x[a, b] + y[a, c] && b == x[a, b] + z[b, c] && 
        c == y[a, c] + z[b, c], {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> (a == 0 && b == 1 && c == 1) || (a == 2 && b == 2 && c == 2)
> ```

Comment: or `FindInstance[a == x[a, b] + y[a, c] && b == x[a, b] + z[b, c] && c == y[a, c] + z[b, c], {a, b, c}, 2]`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `FindInstance` since it doesn't decide if the solution set is complete regardless of the fact that sometimes it can find all solutions.

Comment: How would this change if i have 3rd option in one/all of the "if" instances? Boule can't work anymore...

Comment: @Andreas You are welcome.  In more complicated conditions instead of `Boole` you can use `Switch` or you can define functions with `Condition`  (shorthand: `/;`).  See the documentation pages or you can find similar problems here on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way (this is answer to original question, see Artes answer):

```
bfun[a_, b_, c_] := Boole[{a >= b, a >= c, b >= c}]
an[x_, y_, 
  z_] := {#1, #3, #2} & @@ (Total /@ Partition[{x, y, z}, 2, 1, 1])
t = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];
lhs = an @@@ (bfun @@@ (an @@@ t));
rhs = an @@@ t;
crit = MapThread[#1 == #2 &, {lhs, rhs}];
pck = Pick[t, crit];
TableForm[Join[{##}, an@##] & @@@ pck, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C"}}]
```

[image]